# Correct way to close an opencv stream using Flask response

Tags: python, opencv, flask

I have a couple rtsp streams which i need to display in browser.
Currently i'm using opencv's cv2.VideoCapture to do that.
It does the trick but when client side stop recieving the stream (i.e. closes browser window) it looks like even tho video capture stops, CameraStream object instance is still in a memory. 
I don't have any external references to it.

How can i close those in a correct way?

Here's my code:

```
    class Stream(Resource):

        def get(self, id):

            self.id = id
            response = Response(Stream.gen_frame(self),
                            mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
            return response


        def gen_frame(self):
            """
            Video stream generator
            """
            self.cap = CameraStream(cameras[self.id]).start()

            while self.cap:

                frame = self.cap.read()
                convert = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)[1].tobytes()

                yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                       b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + convert + b'\r\n')  # concate frame one by one and show result

                time.sleep(0.05)

            self.cap.stop()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            self.cap.stream.release()
            print("done")
```

And CameraStream class:

```
class CameraStream(object):
    thread = None
    frame = None
    last_access = 0

    def __init__(self, stream, src=0):
        self.stream = cv2.VideoCapture(stream)

        (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.stream.read()
        self.started = False
        self.read_lock = Lock()

    def start(self):
        if self.started:
            print("already started!!")
            return None
        self.started = True
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        self.thread.start()
        return self

    def update(self):
        while self.started:

            (grabbed, frame) = self.stream.read()
            self.read_lock.acquire()
            self.grabbed, self.frame = grabbed, frame
            self.read_lock.release()

    def read(self):
        self.read_lock.acquire()
        if not isinstance(self.frame, (numpy.ndarray)):
            # debugging stuff
            print('achtung', type(self.frame))
            return 0

        frame = self.frame.copy()

        self.read_lock.release()
        return frame

    def stop(self):
        self.started = False
        self.thread.join()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.stream.release()
```

Only idea i had that worked (kind of) was using a global variable to check it's value in each loop iteration. So i could change it globally to stop all streams at once

p.s
I check objects using this code:

```
for x in gc.get_objects():
                if isinstance(x, CameraStream):
                    print(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

the block outside of generator loop was never executed cause response object got deleted before that.

So as solution i just rewrote **del** function like that:

```
def __del__(self):
        try: 
            self.cap.stop()
            self.cap.stream.release()
        except:
            print('probably there\'s no cap yet :(')
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```